# Creating a dropdown to filter by date month (pandas + plotly)

Tags: python, pandas, jupyter-notebook, plotly

[DataFrame](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zADAb.png)

[Current_Graph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Jp8kb.png)

Is it possible for me to integrate a dropdownbox onto this bar graph with 12 selections for each month of the year. When a month is selected the data is filtered for the month and consecutively updates the plotly graph to only display bars for the selected month?

Answer (score 0):

- have simulated data to match structure of your data frame
- you can build **updatemenus** buttons to set the xaxis range.  Have done this dynamically by building another dataframe that contains data to do this in a **list comprehension**

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import plotly.express as px

# simulate data
df = pd.DataFrame({"Date": pd.date_range("1-jun-2020", "now")}).pipe(
    lambda d: d.assign(**{"Time Per Ball (Seconds)": np.random.uniform(20, 51, len(d))})
)

fig = px.bar(df, x="Date", y="Time Per Ball (Seconds)")

dfbut = (
    (df["Date"] + pd.offsets.MonthBegin(-1))
    .drop_duplicates()
    .to_frame()
    .assign(
        label=lambda d: d["Date"].dt.strftime("%b-%Y"),
        start=lambda d: (d["Date"] - pd.Timestamp("1970-01-01")) // pd.Timedelta("1ms"),
        end=lambda d: d["start"].shift(-1),
    )
    .fillna((df["Date"].max() - pd.Timestamp("1970-01-01")) // pd.Timedelta("1ms"))
)

# build buttons to filter by month
fig.update_layout(
    updatemenus=[
        {
            "buttons": [
                {
                    "label": r[1]["label"],
                    "method": "relayout",
                    "args": [{"xaxis": {"range": [r[1]["start"], r[1]["end"]]}}],
                }
                for r in dfbut.iterrows()
            ]
        },
        {"buttons":[{"label":"All data", "method":"relayout","args":[{"xaxis":{"range":[]}}]}],"y":.8,"type":"buttons"}
    ]
)
```

[image]

#### approach with multiple traces

- have a trace for each month.  run new cell after **df** and **dfbut** have been built
- set visibility of traces in update menus
- also use **uirevision** and `{"xaxis": {"autorange": True}` to maintain layout between view switches

```
# add EndDate to make next part simpler
dfbut = dfbut.assign(EndDate=dfbut["Date"].shift(-1) - pd.Timedelta(days=1)).fillna(df["Date"].max())
dfbut = dfbut.loc[~(dfbut["EndDate"] < df["Date"].min())]

# create a trace per month so zoom / pan is maintained between selections
go.Figure(
    [
        px.bar(
            df.loc[df["Date"].between(start, end)],
            x="Date",
            y="Time Per Ball (Seconds)",
        )
        .update_traces(name=label)
        .data[0]
        for label, start, end in dfbut.loc[:, ["label", "Date", "EndDate"]].values
    ]
).update_layout(
    updatemenus=[
        {
            "buttons": [
                {
                    "label": "All",
                    "method": "update",
                    "args": [
                        {"visible": (dfbut["label"] == dfbut["label"]).tolist()},
                        {"xaxis": {"autorange": True}},
                    ],
                }
            ]
            + [
                {
                    "label": l,
                    "method": "update",
                    "args": [
                        {"visible": (dfbut["label"] == l).tolist()},
                        {"xaxis": {"autorange": True}},
                    ],
                }
                for l in dfbut["label"]
            ]
        }
    ],
    xaxis={"autorange": True},
)
```

Comment: Thank you for this however, I have just tried to paste it into jupyter and get the following error: 'TypeError: cannot astype a datetimelike from [datetime64[ns]] to [int32]'

Comment: pandas 1.3.1, plotly 5.1.0.  I suspect a pandas version issue

Comment: I have updated my pandas to 1.3.1 and plotly to 5.1.0 but the same issue still persists. It appears to be coming from line 23.

Comment: I've reworked the way **dfbut** dataframe is built.  Never like leaving warnings

Comment: Would it be possible to configure this to use python's builtin from datetime module i.e. datetime.time, datetime.date, datetime.timedelta, instead of pandas? I have found they are incompatible.

Comment: the purpose of **dfbut** is to generate *list* of buttons that are wanted with datetime parameters that work with plotly range.   This can be done in anyway you want,  then change the list comprehension to build the buttons.  I prefer to work with pandas as I find it more convenient that native lower level python

Comment: Thank you so much Rob. How would I fix the 'half bars'  from displaying at the beginning and the end of each monthly representation. I need these to be full in width.

Comment: Whenever you try to use any of the plotly functionality such as zooming in or out whilst a month is selected, that output will be saved to that month and will forever stay the same when re-selecting the month. Is there any way to reset this so every time a month is selected, even after you played around with the zoom functions it will go back to its original view?

Comment: I've added a button to show "All data".  the way plotly works is that it maintains viewing state,  if you want state to be set on a button click,  then code that as additional parameters in the **relayout** instruction.  I've answered your question,  normal SO etiquette is to accept an answer that meets the posed question

Comment: Im continuously facing the issue of the graph not resetting back to the original state of the month when a month is selected - I have filmed a short screen recording of what it's doing. [link](https://gifyu.com/image/GWY7) How would I make the graph go back to its original October state when the october button is selected? I have been trying to find a solution but to no avail. @Rob 
Raymond

Comment: added another approach, this does treat user interaction in a different way.  what ever way there will be some limitations